# PostgreSQL Cluster vs PostgreSQL Master-Slave Replication

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I want to setup PostgreSQL and PostGIS to run some experiments (geospatial queries).

If I setup a PostgreSQL cluster, this means that the read requests will be distributed across the nodes of the cluster leading to a better performance?

In case of master-slave replication, that is a process of copying data from a database on one server to a database on another server, the main benefit is the distribution of databases to multiple machines, so when the master server has a problem, there is a backup machine with same data available for handling requests without interruption. If I undestand right, the reads will always goes to masternode and when master is down, slave can take it's place.

In PostgreSQL Cluster what is the situation?

Comment: I think you expect a PostgreSQL cluster to be anything else than a database installation.  If this is the case, please read the beginning of https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/creating-cluster.html.  If not, please specify what exactly you are referring to.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @dezno. I want to install postgresql with postgis extension in order to execute some spatiotemporal queries. If I use postgresql cluster the requests are distributed between nodes and can achieve a better performance? Or for my case is better to use a mslaster slave replication?

Comment: A postgresql cluster doesn't have nodes.  It is a single instance of the postgresql database on a single machine.  If you are using some product which creates multi-node systems and chooses to call these a "cluster" despite that name already being in use, then you have to tell us what that product is.

Comment: No I don't use such products. I am new to postgesql and I have not understand the meaning of cluster. So to be more specific, is it possible to have a postgresql " cluster" and the read operation to distribute? Or only the primary server ie the postgesql server can serve queries?

Comment: Also I found this tutorial: https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/postgresql/create-a-highly-available-postgresql-cluster-using-patroni-and-haproxy/ . Is this not the case of a multi node cluster setup with postgresql?